# Error on image capture with camera mode

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm working on image picker with `camera` and `gallery` and using following code to get image captured from camera but `imageurl and image name` is nil.I'm testing on mobile with os version of 11.2.2.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    let imageUrl          = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? NSURL
    let imageName         = imageUrl?.lastPathComponent
    let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first!
    let photoURL          = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectory)
    let localPath         = photoURL.appendingPathComponent(imageName!)

    if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: localPath!.path) {
        do {
            try UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)?.write(to: localPath!)
            print("file saved")
        }catch {
            print("error saving file")
        }
    }
    else {
        print("file already exists")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `UIImagePickerControllerImageURL` instead of `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL` like this:

```
let imageUrl = info[UIImagePickerControllerImageURL] as? NSURL
```

Comment: @ganesh ,this solution also return null..please check it for version 11.2

Answer (score 0):

You will not get any `imageUrl` or `imageName` because you are using the **camera mode** and that image is still not saved in your gallery and hence no image path is created for that camera clicked pic. So they will be nil. You can only get the `UIImage` object `info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]` in this case.

If you pick the image from **photo album**, then you will get everyhting. You can get the url by `info[UIImagePickerControllerImageURL]` and you can grab the name using the last path component.

Change your imagePickerController source to photo `imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary` and then you will get the urls.

Comment: @Maheshwari...info[UIImagePickerControllerImageURL] also returns nill

Comment: @kavithaG It will return nil if you are taking from camera. It will give you only the UIImage which I already mentioned. It will only give info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

Comment: It has nothing to do with version, as the image clicked from camera is not saved anywhere, so no URLs can be found. Only the UIImage object can be found.